# How to fetch relational table data as a json structure

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using laravel and mysql ,i am joining two tables based on conditions it's working fine but my requirement was i have to fetch those details inside json ,can anyone give me some idea how to proceed with this scenario ?

```
Table1::leftJoin(//mycondition)->select('table1.id','table1.name','table2.*')->get()->toArray();
```

**currentResult**

```
[
{
  'id':1,
  'name':'test',
  'tab2id':1,
  'tab2name':'tab2'
}
]
```

**ExpectedResult**

```
[
{
  'id':1,
  'name':'test',
  'tab2':{
         'tab2id':1,
         'tab2name':'tab2'
         }
}
]
```

Comment: use relationship https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

$user = User::find(1);
  $json = $user->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

or
echo json_encode($user, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
or
return Response::json($user, null, null, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
or
return response()->json($user,200,[],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```